# Confidence interval for Accuracy, Precision and Recall

Tags: confidence-interval, accuracy, precision-recall

Classification accuracy or classification error is a proportion or a ratio. It describes the proportion of correct or incorrect predictions made by the model. Each prediction is a binary decision that could be correct or incorrect which is a Bernoulli trial.

The proportions in a Bernoulli trial have a binomial distribution. With large sample sizes (e.g. more than 30), we can approximate the distribution with a Gaussian.

We can use the assumption of a Gaussian distribution of the proportion to calculate the 95% confidence interval for accuracy as:

`radius = z * sqrt( (accuracy * (1 - accuracy)) / n)`

where n is the size of the dataset, and z is the number of standard deviations (z = 1.96 for 95% interval) from the Gaussian distribution.

Can we use the same approach to calculate precision and recall, that are also eventually based on proportion of correct predictions ?

Comment: I doubt that the Gaussian interval you give for the accuracy is valid. Classification accuracy is based on a certain classification  method applied to all training observations at once. Arguably the involved indicators are all dependent (even in a test sample, as you could expect similar misclassification probability for close observations in data space), and this is ignored by standard Bernoulli or Gaussian confidence intervals. A similar issue will apply to precision and recall.

Comment: Yes. In principle the classification of any observation may depend (probabilistically, not perfectly) on the classification of any other observation.

Comment: @ Christian Hennig
So what you say is that predicting True or False for the class is not a Bernoulli trial?

Comment: In general this depends on how you exactly do that. I'm saying it's not a Bernoulli trial if the prediction is done by a method that also relies on other observations, as this introduces dependence.

Comment: @ Christian Hennig What about precision and recall? The same as with accuracy, I think. Or any additional restrictions?

Comment: Should be the same problem; I don't have things on top of that in mind right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gaussian interval for calculating the confidence interval if you have a large enough N.

This is the suggested equation for accuracy:
[image]

I don't see why the same shouldn't apply to recall, precision etc.

equation source: "Introduction to Data Mining" by Pang-Nin Tan, Michael Steinbach... pg 190. This is specifically for classification confidence intervals

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It may be edit your answer to include [LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions) formatting.